# Application exits while requesting permission

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have this piece of code in the SplashActivity that requests ReadPhoneState permissions to call an ASyncTask. On the first run, the activity finishes (not crashes) and then the permissions dialog appears. I grant permission and re-enter the app and it starts normally. So why is the splash finishing at the first run in the first place?

Here's my code:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    boolean noConMessage = false, granted = false;
    boolean firstRun;
    int caller = 0;
    int channelId = 0;
    Bundle bundle;
    String deviceId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        MyApplication.crashBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        final SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        MyApplication.fontSize = Integer.parseInt(settings.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.textsize_key), "15").toString());
        firstRun = settings.getBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.firstRun_key), true);
        deviceId = settings.getString(getResources().getString(R.string.deviceId_key), "-1");


        /*if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);
                    Launching mLaunching = new Launching();
                    mLaunching.execute();
        }else{
            Launching mLaunching = new Launching();
            mLaunching.execute();
        }*/

        int hasReadPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if (hasReadPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    123);
            return;
        }

        //  CheckNewVersionAsyncTask mCheckNewVersionAsyncTask=new CheckNewVersionAsyncTask(this);
        //  mCheckNewVersionAsyncTask.execute();

        Launching mLaunching = new Launching();
        mLaunching.execute();

    }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 123:
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission Granted
                    Launching mLaunching = new Launching();
                    mLaunching.execute();
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied

                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    public void loadPage() {
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                ChannelListActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, Constants.IMAGES);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        if (noConMessage) {
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();


    }

    protected class Launching extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... a) {
            try {
                if (deviceId.equals("-1")) {

                    ServerUtilities.addDevice(SplashActivity.this);
                    GCMRegistrar.unregister(SplashActivity.this);
                } else {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) 0.25);
                }
                if (true) {
                    Actions.copyFile(SplashActivity.this, "tahoma.ttf");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
            if (firstRun) {
                PushNotificationActions.registerNotification(SplashActivity.this);
            } else {
                loadPage();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove this `finish();` call from `onpause` function because when dialog appear your activity will go in `onpause` state and the `finish` call will `destroy` your activity

Answer (score 0):

Remove return statement and put your launching code in else block and also remove finish from pause :

```
int hasReadPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(SplashActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        if (hasReadPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SplashActivity.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    123);

        }else {
        Launching mLaunching = new Launching();
        mLaunching.execute();
    }
```